# Django related model not updating related object in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have 2 models that look like this:

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    deal = models.ManyToManyField('Deal', related_name="clients")

class Deal(models.Model):
    client = models.ManyToManyField(Client, related_name="deals")
```

Then in the admin, I have inlined the related models to make it easy to make changes regardless of the object type you have open.

**admin.py**

```
class ClientInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Deal.client.through

class DealAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ClientInline]

class DealInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Client.deal.through

class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DealInline]
```

However, if you add a `Client` to a `Deal` and then open the `Client` detail page, the corresponding deal does not appear. Is there something I'm not connecting?

Comment: did you check the DB if the changes have been updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this an you were actually really close.

**First**, [@wowkin2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3722635/wowkin2) said, you don't want to define a `ManyToManyField` in both models so I would probably just define it in your `Deal` model.

**Second**, replace this:

```
class DealInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Client.deal.through
```

with this:

```
class DealInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Deal.client.through
```

And everything should work.

---

So, this is what your files should now look like:

**models.py**

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    client = models.ManyToManyField(Client, related_name="deals")
```

**admin.py**

```
class ClientInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Deal.client.through

class DealAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ClientInline]

class DealInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Deal.client.through

class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DealInline]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to have relation define only in one model. Otherwise you'll have 2 separate tables for separate ManyToMany relation: ClientDeal and DealClient.

What you need to do is to choose which one you need to leave. And probably update Admin inlines according to [Django Admin documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

```
class Client(models.Model):
    deals = models.ManyToManyField('Deal', related_name="clients")


class Deal(models.Model):
    pass
```

Comment: Okay, so then is it not possible to display the deal inline on the client change page?

Comment: You can just define your model without `.client.through`. Read more about that in documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

If you'll still have questions - let me know.

Comment: @Ryan does this helped?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you're using models.manytoMany() , you have to put it only in one model. no the two

But there's a very good attribute you should use: **through**
with through attribute you can create a intermediate model. here there's an example:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('Group', through='GroupMember', related_name='people')

class Meta:
    ordering = ['name']

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['name']

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class GroupMember(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='membership')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='membership')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s is in group %s (as %s)" % (self.person, self.group, self.type))
```

later, you can use your inline admin class!